# Select multiple images and display them in image views

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

I am trying to choose and display multiple images (approx. 5 images) but for some reason I am only able to select and display a single image at a time. I have tried to implement the below code for displaying multiple images. Please help guys. Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  {

    let imagesData = [UIImage]()

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView4: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myImageView.backgroundColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)
        myImageView1.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1)
        myImageView2.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.06274510175, green: 0, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
        myImageView3.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5791940689, green: 0.1280144453, blue: 0.5726861358, alpha: 1)
        myImageView4.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        myImageView.image = image
        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        myImageView1.image = image
        myImageView1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        myImageView2.image = image
        myImageView2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        myImageView3.image = image
        myImageView3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        myImageView4.image = image
        myImageView4.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: From your code, you are setting an image to all image views.

Comment: please used any library for done it

Comment: https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController GOOD library for selecting multiple images

Comment: @MahendraGP Yes I know. I have done that for testing purpose

Comment: @Jaydip Ok. Please can you suggest me few libraries?

Comment: Please used https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker library

Comment: @Jaydip Thanks man. Do you know any tutorial for using such libraries on web?

Comment: i don't know if it's available or not but i already used this library @Saurabh

Comment: ok. Have you referred to any site or book?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `UIImagePickerController` and it don't allow multiple selection of images.

If you want to  select multiple images at a time then you need to create your own custom image picker controller.

Another way is that, when user select an image the set that image in `imageview1` and present image picker controller again to select 2nd image, and so on...until your image count reaches 5.

Comment: The thing is I have to select atmost 5 images i.e. it can be less than 5 images.

Comment: then take user input for number of images to be selected and open image picker view controller according to that..

Comment: Can't it be possible without user input?

Comment: possible but you need to use some static value let say `numberOfImages = 5` so you need to open image picker view 5 time to select 5 image from gallery.

Comment: yes exactly...can we select multiple images just like we do while selecting images in whatsapp using a single image picker?

Comment: For that you need to create a custom image picker view or use third party apis. You can check iOS version of WhatsApp it won't allow you to select multiple images from image picker controller, but instead you need to select multiple images form gallery and share to WhatsApp  I've tried it.

Comment: My only target is to select few images and display them in image views..

Comment: Picking the images from photos will also do..right...but i am having problem using the custom image picker..as i don't know about it's usage..so can you please help by giving a simple example with custom image picker because i haven't used it before

Comment: If you want to create your own custom image picker view then you need to use `Photos.framework` to get all photos from gallery and display in a view controller and you can display collection view to show images and set flag to select multiple images and on btnOK click return all images in your required view controller.

Comment: Or if you don't want to create your own then there there are many third party library available that can be used....just read its documentation carefully :)

Comment: ok I will try it and if it does work..I will inform you regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third party libraries out there but BSImagePicker helped me resolve my problem and I have been using this library for a while now.

Here's the link -> https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker

Hope it helps you as well!